# API connection and getting the returned result

Tags: python, django

I'm sorry for my bad english

Hello, I am using a brokerage firm for payment instrument. The API connection is successful and I get the result. But I can't use the returned result information.

```
payment_card = {
            'cardHolderName': kartisim,
            'cardNumber': kartno,
            'expireMonth': kartskt_ay,
            'expireYear': '2030',
            'cvc': karcvc,
            'registerCard': '0'
        }
        buyer = {
            'id': adres.id,
            'name': adres.adres_uye.username,
            'surname': 'Doe',
            'gsmNumber': '+905350000000',
            'email': adres.adres_uye.email,
            'identityNumber': '74300864791',
            'lastLoginDate': '2015-10-05 12:43:35',
            'registrationDate': '2013-04-21 15:12:09',
            'registrationAddress': adres.adres_detay,
            'ip': '85.34.78.112',
            'city': 'Istanbul',
            'country': 'Turkey',
            'zipCode': '34732'
        }
        address = {
            'contactName': 'Jane Doe',
            'city': 'Istanbul',
            'country': 'Turkey',
            'address': 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
            'zipCode': '34732'
        }            
        
        basket_items = []
        for bas in uye:
            basa = {
                'id': str(bas.id),
                'name': str(bas.sepet_urun.urun_baslik),
                'category1': str(bas.sepet_urun.urun_anakategori.anakategori_baslik),
                'category2': str(bas.sepet_urun.urun_altkategori.altkategori_baslik),
                'itemType': 'VIRTUAL',
                'price': str(bas.sepet_fiyat)
            }
            basket_items.append(basa)            
        print(basket_items)
        
        request_payload = {
            'locale': 'tr',
            'conversationId': '123456789',
            'price': str(sepetf),
            'paidPrice': str(sepetf),
            'currency': 'TRY',
            'installment': '1',
            'basketId': str(sepetid),
            'paymentChannel': 'WEB',
            'paymentGroup': 'PRODUCT',
            'paymentCard': payment_card,
            'buyer': buyer,
            'shippingAddress': address,
            'billingAddress': address,
            'basketItems': basket_items
        }
        
        payment = iyzipay.Payment().create(request_payload, options)
        print(payment.read().decode('utf-8'))
        return HttpResponse(payment["status"])
```

I cannot use the returned result information. The returned result is as follows
[image]

The error I get is as follows:
**'HTTPResponse' object is not subscriptable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is here.

```
return HttpResponse(payment["status"])
```

`payment` returns an [`HTTPResponse` response](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) object and you cannot directly index the `status`. Instead you should use [`.status` attribute.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.status)

If your intention is to return JSON back as response you could use [`JsonResponse` class from `django.http` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse).

```
return JsonResponse(json.loads(payment.read().decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But as a result, it returned 200, don't you think it should be successful? Could it be a problem with the service provider?

Comment: @yumlusoft `200` means [request has succeeded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)